# Remove active class from zurb foundation tabs

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation tabs on part of a web application, however the default desired behavior is for all the tabs on the document to be closed.  However I cannot get the tabs to initialize in this manner.

Since I did not find an option for this I am trying to remove the active class from all the tabs on the page that match the below selector.

However the remove of the class is occurring before the class is applied by Foundation.

How can I remove the active class after it is added, or alternatively how can I not have it add the active class in the first place?

```
$(document).foundation();
$(window).load(function(){
  alert("in load");
  $('.contextDropDown p').parent().each(function(){
    alert("im here");
   $(this).removeClass("active");});
});
```

http://jsbin.com/olidux/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Foundation 4, at the time of this post beginning on line 180 of the **foundation.section.js** file you'll see the following lines:

```
if (settings.one_up || !self.small($this)) {
    first.addClass('active');
}
```

Comment out these lines (the second one specifically) to prevent the first tab being initialized with the **active** class.

Comment: While this works, it is usually not good practice to edit the framework itself.  Hopefully foundation actually implements the one_up setting in section.